# Request map direct me to Login page in Grails

Tags: grails, spring-security

I'm trying to make a website using Grails 3.10 and the spring-security-core plugin.
I am so new on that. I genereate my all domain classses then run the application.
And it direct me to login page. This is a good thing actually but for now how can get through this and can see my other controlers and views. I read some blogs. I guess write some codes like

```
import org.codehaus.groovy.grails.plugins.springsecurity.Secured
class SecureAnnotatedController {

  @Secured(['ROLE_ADMIN'])
  def index = {
    render 'you have ROLE_ADMIN'
   }

  @Secured(['ROLE_ADMIN', 'ROLE_ADMIN2'])
  def adminEither = {
     render 'you have ROLE_ADMIN or ROLE_ADMIN2'
   }

   def anybody = {
     render 'anyone can see this'
    }
  }
```

but I could not understand. Thanks for any help.

Comment: Tell me : what does browser display when you open `http://localhost:8080/secureAnnotated/adminEither` & when you open `http://localhost:8080/secureAnnotated/anybody`

Comment: direct me to login page again

Comment: for both ? or for the 1st URL only

Comment: for both direct to login page

Comment: If you're using Grails 3.x, then including `import org.codehaus.groovy.grails.plugins.springsecurity.Secured` should not compile because that is from a version of the Grails 2 plugin that is years old. The plugin docs are [here](https://grails-plugins.github.io/grails-spring-security-core/v3/index.html) and you should at least work through the tutorial first. You're also using old Grails syntax, so there could be many problems in your app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import grails.plugin.springsecurity.annotation.Secured
class SecureAnnotatedController {

  @Secured(['ROLE_ADMIN'])
  def index() {
    render text: 'you have ROLE_ADMIN'
   }

  @Secured(['ROLE_ADMIN', 'ROLE_ADMIN2'])
  def adminEither() { 
     render text: 'you have ROLE_ADMIN or ROLE_ADMIN2'
   }

   def anybody () { 
     render text: 'anyone can see this'
    }
  }
```

As Burt has pointed out you are using old controller methods and an old Secured import

Beyond this:

Take a look at grails-app/conf/application.groov:

```
grails.plugin.springsecurity.controllerAnnotations.staticRules = [
        [pattern: '/',               access: ['permitAll']],
        [pattern: '/error',          access: ['permitAll']],
        [pattern: '/SecureAnnotatedController/anybody',          access: ['permitAll']],
        [pattern: '/index/**',          access: ['permitAll']],
```

In above I have directly added /SecureAnnotatedController/anybody if you have that in the midst of the existing default values then it should work.

You could also instead of updating applucation.groovy use `@Secured(['permitAll'])` above the method.

**above should make what you need work. Below is more advanced and covers locking failed attempts**
This is a great plugin and needs time to absorb its delicate details.

In regards to above posts:

```
//grails.plugin.springsecurity.successHandler.defaultTargetUrl = "/helloAgain/${System.currentTimeMillis()}"
//grails.plugins.springsecurity.useSecurityEventListener = true

grails.plugin.springsecurity.successHandler.alwaysUseDefault = true
grails.plugin.springsecurity.useRoleGroups = true


brutforce {
    loginAttempts {
        time = 5
        allowedNumberOfAttempts = 3
    }
}
```

I originally had it going to helloAgain which did a redirect but at this point was a hackish way of registering the incoming user. Now I am using

```
grails.plugin.springsecurity.useSecurityEventListener = true
```

Which then feeds into grails-app/conf/spring/resources.groovy

```
import myapp.utils.CustomSecurityEventListener
import myapp.utils.CustomSecurityFailureEventListener
import myapp.utils.RedirectFailureToRegistration
import org.springframework.security.web.authentication.SimpleUrlAuthenticationFailureHandler

// Place your Spring DSL code here
beans = {
    redirectFailureHandlerExample(SimpleUrlAuthenticationFailureHandler) {
        defaultFailureUrl = '/failed'
    }

    redirectFailureHandler(RedirectFailureToRegistration) {
        defaultFailureUrl = '/failed'
        registrationUrl = '/'
    }
    /*
    multipartResolver(ContentLengthAwareCommonsMultipartResolver) {
        defaultEncoding = 'UTF-8'
    }
    */
    customerSecurityEventListener(CustomSecurityEventListener)
    customSecurityFailureEventListener(CustomSecurityFailureEventListener)
```

Now these files: in my src/main/groovy/myapp/utils  I have

```
package myapp.utils

import grails.util.Holders
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationListener
import org.springframework.security.authentication.event.AuthenticationSuccessEvent
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetails

class CustomSecurityEventListener implements ApplicationListener<AuthenticationSuccessEvent> {
    //private static Collection activeUsers = Collections.synchronizedList(new ArrayList())
    def loginAttemptCacheService = Holders.grailsApplication.mainContext.getBean('loginAttemptCacheService')

    void onApplicationEvent(AuthenticationSuccessEvent event) {
        def userDetails = (UserDetails) event.getAuthentication().getPrincipal()
        if (userDetails) {
            //SessionListener.userLoggedIn(userDetails.getUsername())
            loginAttemptCacheService.loginSuccess(event.authentication.name)
        }
    }
    // public static Collection getActiveUsers() {
    //     return Collections.unmodifiableList(activeUsers)
    //  }

}


package myapp.utils

import myapp.users.LoginAttemptCacheService
import grails.util.Holders
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationListener
import org.springframework.security.authentication.event.AuthenticationFailureBadCredentialsEvent

class CustomSecurityFailureEventListener implements ApplicationListener<AuthenticationFailureBadCredentialsEvent> {

    def loginAttemptCacheService = Holders.grailsApplication.mainContext.getBean('loginAttemptCacheService')

    void onApplicationEvent(AuthenticationFailureBadCredentialsEvent event) {
        String username = (String) event.getAuthentication().getPrincipal()
        if (username) {
            loginAttemptCacheService.failLogin(event.authentication.name)
        }
    }

}
```

The service:

```
import com.google.common.cache.CacheBuilder
import com.google.common.cache.CacheLoader
import com.google.common.cache.LoadingCache
import grails.core.GrailsApplication
import grails.core.support.GrailsApplicationAware
import grails.transaction.Transactional

import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit
import org.apache.commons.lang.math.NumberUtils
import javax.annotation.PostConstruct

class LoginAttemptCacheService implements GrailsApplicationAware {
    def config
    GrailsApplication grailsApplication
    private LoadingCache attempts
    private int allowedNumberOfAttempts


    @PostConstruct
    void init() {
        allowedNumberOfAttempts = config.brutforce.loginAttempts.allowedNumberOfAttempts
        int time = config.brutforce.loginAttempts.time
        log.info "account block configured for $time minutes"
        attempts = CacheBuilder.newBuilder()
                .expireAfterWrite(time, TimeUnit.MINUTES)
                .build({0} as CacheLoader);
    }

    /**
     * Triggers on each unsuccessful login attempt and increases number of attempts in local accumulator
     * @param login - username which is trying to login
     * @return
     */
    def failLogin(String login) {
        def numberOfAttempts = attempts.get(login)
        log.debug "fail login $login previous number for attempts $numberOfAttempts"
        numberOfAttempts++
        if (numberOfAttempts > allowedNumberOfAttempts) {
            blockUser(login)
            attempts.invalidate(login)
        } else {
            attempts.put(login, numberOfAttempts)
        }
    }

    /**
     * Triggers on each successful login attempt and resets number of attempts in local accumulator
     * @param login - username which is login
     */
    def loginSuccess(String login) {
        log.debug "successfull login for $login"
        attempts.invalidate(login)
    }

    /**
     * Disable user account so it would not able to login
     * @param login - username that has to be disabled
     */
    @Transactional
    private void blockUser(String login) {
        log.debug "blocking user: $login"
            def user = User.findByUsername(login)
            if (user) {
                user.accountLocked = true
                user.save(flush: true)
            }
    }

    void setGrailsApplication(GrailsApplication ga) {
        config = ga.config
    }
}
```

For all that cool stuff to work you will need to also add this to your build.gradle

```
//caching user failure attempts //CustomerSecurityFailureEventListener.groovy
    compile 'com.google.guava:guava:11.0.1'
```

Enjoy

Comment: I commented out //SessionListener.userLoggedIn since it was not included. This simply kept a listing if sessions logged in. If you get stuck give me a shout.

Answer (score 0):

For the later versions of Spring Security with Grails  ,  you need to add the following to Conf's file :

## Config.groovy :

```
grails.plugin.springsecurity.successHandler.alwaysUseDefault = true
grails.plugin.springsecurity.successHandler.defaultTargetUrl = '/your-url'
```

Instead of: