# Grails security implementation

Tags: grails

I made the following Controller.
I can login and logout, but how can I force the the user to log in first?
I need to start a session on login and terminate it on logout.

```
class UserController {
   def scaffold = User
   def login = {}
   def authenticate = {
      def user = User.findByLoginAndPassword(params.login, params.password)
      if(user){
         session.user = user
         flash.message = "Hello ${user.name}!"
         redirect(controller:"entry", action:"list")      
      } else {
         flash.message = "Sorry, ${params.login}. Please try again."
         redirect(action:"login")
      }
   }

   def logout = {
      flash.message = "Goodbye ${session.user.name}"
      session.user = null
      redirect(controller:"entry", action:"list")      
   }  
}
```

Comment: I think this will help. I think you want a way of recognising users that login http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38688075/request-map-direct-me-to-login-page-in-grails/38793608#38793608

Comment: Corrected grammar errors, tightened terminology, and fixed code formatting.

Answer (score 1):

**Choice 1:**

There are number of security plugins available for securing your Grail's app.

The most popular one is the **"Spring Security Core Plugin"** which will force user to login before accessing your secured resource.

Reference Link :  http://grails.org/plugin/spring-security-core

**Choice 2 :**

But if you don't want to use any external plugin for you application(I would suggest to use one) you can take advantage of **"Filters"** in Grail's

You can create a filter for checking the session before user hits any action of your controller and if session is already expired/not created then you can redirect them to login page.

**Example :**

```
class SecurityFilterFilters {

    def filters = {
        loginCheck(controller: 'Your_controller_name(if many separate them with pipe(|) )', action: "*") {
            before = {
                //check if user is logged in(if yes then there will be session.user) and action is not login action 
                if (!session.user && !actionName.equals('login')) {
                    //user is not logged in so redirect him to login page
                    redirect(controller: 'user', action: 'login')
                    return false
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Reference Link :** http://docs.grails.org/2.2.1/ref/Plug-ins/filters.html

Answer (score 0):

See the 'Secured annotation' spring-security-core plugin documentation for Grails

https://grails-plugins.github.io/grails-spring-security-core/v3/